# Postgres creating new db from old db

Tags: postgresql-9.1

I have a dump.pgsql from a Postgres Database . I am trying to import the same to a new database on a different host. Database name is same. 
But i am not able to proceed. On psql page i am giving this command
psql postgres postgres

I am getting this output

```
                                              List of roles
```

Role name    |            Attributes             |                         Me
mber of

### ----------------+-----------------------------------+---------------------------

postgres       | Superuser, Create role, Create DB | {}

I am not able to import this. 
I am very new to this database. So pardon my ignorance .

Appreciate your support.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create dump and then restore on another host, in that way:

```
$ pg_dump -h host -U postgres -Fc test > test.dump
$ pg_restore -h second_host -U postgres -d second_test test.dump
```

Before you restore you'll need to create 'second_test' schema (which must be the same as 'test').

You will find more details at [PostgresQL Documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/app-pgdump.html)

Comment: Thanks for your reply, i have the dump of entire database which has 6 schemas, i have created similar roles in new database. Dump file has create schema statements.

Comment: also my second host in windows. and on that i am not able to run pg_restore

Comment: I am able to run pg_restore after adding the bin directory to the path environment variables.